# Write raw memory to file

Tags: c++, c, file, malloc, dump

I am trying to dump the memory (made with malloc) to a file. I want to dump the raw data because I don't know what's inside the memory (int float double) at the point that I want to dump the memory.
What's the best way to do this?
I have tried a few thing already but non of them worked as i wanted.

Comment: Can you show us these few things?

Comment: What gave you tried? How do you know it didn't work?

Comment: C or C++ ? (They are two very different languages.) If you're using malloc then it sounds like you are using C, not C++ ?

Answer (score 4):

In C, it's quite trivial, really:

```
const size_t size = 4711;
void *data = malloc(size);
if(data != NULL)
{
  FILE *out = fopen("memory.bin", "wb");
  if(out != NULL)
  {
    size_t to_go = size;
    while(to_go > 0)
    {
      const size_t wrote = fwrite(data, to_go, 1, out);
      if(wrote == 0)
        break;
      to_go -= wrote;
    }
    fclose(out);
  }
  free(data);
}
```

The above attempts to properly loop `fwrite()` to handle short writes, that's where most of the complexity comes from.

Comment: You have a bug in your code. fwrite returns the number of elements written not the number of bytes written to file. Basically your code just creates a huge file and the loop never gets to end until either the disk is full or some memory/disk allocation limits are reached. Please correct it. :)

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you mean by "not working".

You could `reinterpret_cast` the memory to a `char *` and write it to file easily.
Reading it back again is a different matter.

Answer (score 3):

The "C++ way" of doing it would probably involve using `std::ostream::write` with a stream in binary mode.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

bool write_file_binary (std::string const & filename, 
  char const * data, size_t const bytes)
{
  std::ofstream b_stream(filename.c_str(), 
    std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
  if (b_stream)
  {
    b_stream.write(data, bytes);
    return (b_stream.good());
  }
  return false;
}


int main (void)
{
  double * buffer = new double[100];
  write_file_binary("test.bin", 
    reinterpret_cast<char const *>(buffer), 
    sizeof(double)*100);
  delete[] buffer;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is C++, this might help you, as part of serializing and deserializing,
I write the raw memory array to a file (using new[] is essentially the same
as malloc in the C world):

https://github.com/goblinhack/simple-c-plus-plus-serializer

```
    #include "hexdump.h"

    auto elems = 128;

    static void serialize (std::ofstream out)
    {
        auto a = new char[elems];
        for (auto i = 0; i > bits(a);

        hexdump(a, elems);
    }
```

Output:

```
    128 bytes:
    0000 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f |................|
    0010 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f |................|
    0020 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27  28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f | !"#$%&'()*+,-./|
    0030 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37  38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f |0123456789:;?|
    0040 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47  48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f |@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO|
    0050 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57  58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f |PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_|
    0060 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67  68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f |`abcdefghijklmno|
    0070 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77  78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f |pqrstuvwxyz{|}~.|
```